# How can I remove all rows that aren't the newest N for each user in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, database

Assuming I have a table `foo` where I have something like this:

`id`, `user_id`, `timestamp`, `some_value`

What I want to do is remove all rows that aren't the newest N **per user**.

The deletion itself could be handled by a:

```
DELETE FROM foo WHERE id NOT IN (...)
```

so you could rephrase the problem into: How do I get the newest N(there might be less) rows **for each user**. This means if I have U users I may end up with N*U rows so `LIMIT` wont really work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL does not support reading from a table with `SELECT` and performing an `UPDATE`/`INSERT`/`DELETE` on the same table in the same query.  So doing what you want in one statement is going to be tricky.

I would do it in two stages:  first, query the newest `$N` records per user, and store them in a temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo_top_n
  SELECT f1.id
  FROM foo f1 LEFT OUTER JOIN foo f2
    ON (f1.user_id = f2.user_id AND f1.id < f2.id)
  GROUP BY f1.id
  HAVING COUNT(*) < $N;
```

Next, use the multi-table `DELETE` syntax and join `foo` to the temporary table, deleting where no match is found:

```
DELETE f1 FROM foo f1 LEFT OUTER JOIN foo_top_n f2 USING (id)
WHERE f2.id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it is possible to do it a single query:

```
DELETE  l.*
FROM    foo l
JOIN    (
        SELECT  user_id,
                COALESCE(
                (
                SELECT  timestamp
                FROM    foo li
                WHERE   li.user_id = dlo.user_id
                ORDER BY
                        li.user_id DESC, li.timestamp DESC
                LIMIT 2, 1
                ), CAST('0001-01-01' AS DATETIME)) AS mts,
                COALESCE(
                (
                SELECT  id
                FROM    foo li
                WHERE   li.user_id = dlo.user_id
                ORDER BY
                        li.user_id DESC, li.timestamp DESC, li.id DESC
                LIMIT 2, 1
                ), -1) AS mid
        FROM    (
                SELECT  DISTINCT user_id
                FROM    foo dl
                ) dlo
        ) lo
ON      l.user_id = lo.user_id
        AND (l.timestamp, l.id) < (mts, mid)
```

See detailed explanations here:

- [**Keeping rows**](http://explainextended.com/2009/04/07/keeping-rows/) (how to delete all rows except `TOP N`)
- [**Advanced row sampling**](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/06/advanced-row-sampling/) (how to select `TOP N` rows for each `GROUP`)
- [**Keeping latest rows for a group**](http://explainextended.com/2009/04/26/keeping-latest-rows-for-a-group/) (how to use the approaches above together)

Answer (score 0):

First, get the total number of rows using this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM foo WHERE id NOT IN (...)
```

Then try this:

```
DELETE FROM foo WHERE id NOT IN (...) ORDER BY timestamp ASC LIMIT (Count - N)
```

replacing N by your number. This will delete all except the newest N rows. For example,
if there are a total of 100 rows and you want the newest 5 to be saved, this will delete (100-5) the oldest 95 rows.

Comment: In that case you would change the query to: Where id=user_id. I assume you have a list of all the ids in an array, you'd loop over each id and have this query executed for them

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM foo WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT id FROM foo ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT N )
```

**Edit:**

I misunderstood the question. you want to keep N records for each user. 
Maybe this:

```
SELECT user_id FROM foo
```

Then for each user_id (as currentID):

```
DELETE FROM foo WHERE user_id=currentID AND id NOT IN ( SELECT id FROM foo WHERE user_id=currentID ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT N )
```

(i'm not very sure about the syntax, but i hope the idea is clear)